# Switch Case is not working properly in TabActivity's Fragment

Tags: android, swipe, tabactivity

I'm working on tabactivity's fragment but i'm facing an issue like When i swipe the tab fragment then same UI of tab1 will appear on tab2 i.e.Switch case is not working properly inside placeholder class.While Tab1 and Tab2 having different UI.
Please help me i'm new to android.

```
 public View onCreateView(
        @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_tab, container, false);


    View root = null;
    switch (1) {
        case 1:
            root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_tab, container, false);
            break;
        case 2:
            root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team_screen_, container, false);
            break;
    }

    Next = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_expand);
    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            updatedetails();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: with your current code, `case 1` always true

Comment: what should i change then?

Answer (score 1):

Becuase you have done the mistake in swtich statement

```
switch (1) { // 1 for all the condition
        case 1:
            root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_tab, container, false);
            break;
        case 2:
            root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team_screen_, container, false);
            break;
    }
```

you need to pass the position here like this

```
switch (position) { // here position of the fragment
        case 1:
            root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_tab, container, false);
            break;
        case 2:
            root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_team_screen_, container, false);
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass tab position like,

```
switch (tabPosition) { // here position of the fragment to show
    case 1:
        // your code logic
        break;
    case 2:
        // your code logic
        break;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me is it ok to place this code inside OnCreateView of placeholder class

Comment: After the onCreate() is called in Fragment, the Fragment's onCreateView() is called, so it will be fine.